# Nginx redirect IP:PORT to domain name

Tags: nginx, redirect

My webserver is running at port `4000` and I have configured `nginx` to serve over an HTTPS using a domain name. My application and configuration are working well, but the app is also serving requests using `SERVER_PUBLIC_IP:<PORT>`. I have added an additional server bock in the configuration which is successfully redirecting `SERVER_PUBLIC_IP` request to the domain name, but not able to redirect `SERVER_PUBLIC_IP:4000` to the domain name.

Below is the `nginx` configuration:

```
server {
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level    6;
  gzip_types application/javascript text/css text/plain application/json;
  gzip_min_length 1000;

  root /var/www/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  listen 80;

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;

  server_name my.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name 13.250.13.202;
  return 301 https://my.domain.com;
}
```

I want to configure it so that It also redirects request with `IP:4000`. I tried adding below but It is not working.

```
server {
  listen 4000;
  listen [::]:4000 ipv6only=on;
  server_name 13.250.13.202:4000;
  return 301 https://my.domain.com;
}
```

This gives error:

```
Mar 28 07:59:36 ip-172-31-11-93 nginx[29637]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:4000 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I am clueless which way to tryout. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please remove :4000 from server_name, reload nginx and try.

Comment: @vcode Tried, It didn't work :(

Comment: Is any other process already running on port 4000?

Comment: Yes, my application is running on port 4000

Comment: This must be the reason for nginx not able to bind to port 4000. Please use IPTABLES to redirect 4000 to 80 and nginx will then take care of redirection. Example for redirction using iptables: iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 4000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80